# How to retrieve data correctly in this GridView using Linq-to-Entities?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, linq-to-entities

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am trying to learn Linq-To-Entities. I have a very weird problem. I have the following two tables or entities in my database:

```
Items Table: ID, Code, Name, StatusID
Status Table: ID, Name
```

I tried to view all some details of the items in a GridView. For example, I just want to show two columns from the table such as Name and Code in the GridView. I am trying to develop a general get data method that will retrieve all the details from the table. However, I want later on to specify which column to be displayed in the GridView. 
Here's my method:

```
public IEnumerable<Items> getData()
    {
        List<Items> itemsList = new List<Items>();
        using (ItemsDBEntities context = new ItemsDBEntities())
        {
            itemsList = (from item in context.Items
                        select new Items()
                        {
                            ID = item.ID,
                            Code = item.Code,
                            Name = item.Name
                        }).ToList();
        }
        return itemsList;
    }
```

and I am binding the GridView to this method. But **how can I specify two columns to be displayed instead of all columns without changing the method?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the markup set `AutoGenerateColumns = "false"` for the `GridView` and use `TemplateField`s like below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Id") %> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```